No funciona boton "comprar" en carrito con php
Tengo dos tablas en my sql, una con productos y otra con la compra seleccionada. El objetivo es insertar un producto en la tabla de compras de mysql y en la tabla en pantalla.
Este es el código de la base de datos en la carpeta clases
<?php
class Basededatos {
    private $conexion;
    function __construct($servidor, $usuario, $contrasena, $base){
        $this->conexion = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $contrasena, $base);
}

    public function ejecutarQuery($consulta){
        $instruc = strtoupper(substr($consulta, 0,6)); 
        switch ($instruc) {
            case 'INSERT':
            case 'UPDATE':
            case 'DELETE':
                $SQL = $this->conexion->query($consulta);
                break;
            
            case 'SELECT':
                $SQL = $this->conexion->query($consulta);
                while($listarCont = $SQL->fetch_assoc()){
                    $mostrarCont[] = $listarCont;
                }
                return $mostrarCont;
                break;
        }
    }
} 

La clase de productos en la carpeta clases donde tengo el metodo para listarlos
<?php
class Productos {
    public $base;

    function __construct($baseconectada){
        $this->base = $baseconectada;
    }

    public function listarProductos (){
        $codSQL = $this->base->ejecutarQuery("SELECT * FROM productos");
        return $codSQL;
    }
} 

La clase carrito en la carpeta clases, donde tengo los métodos para insertar y eliminar la compra.
<?php
class Carrito {
    public $base;

    function __construct($baseconectada){
        $this->base = $baseconectada;
    }

    public function introducir_compra($codigo) {
        $this->base->ejecutarQuery("INSERT INTO compras (SELECT producto, descripcion, precio FROM productos WHERE codigo=$codigo)");
    } 
    public function eliminar_compra($cod) {
        $this->base->ejecutarQuery("DELETE FROM compras WHERE codigo=$cod");
    }

    public function listar_compra(){
        $codSQL = $this->base->ejecutarQuery("SELECT * FROM compras");
        return $codSQL;
    }
}

Tengo una carpeta en componentes donde instancio las clases
<?php
include('clases/basededatos.php');
include('clases/productos.php');


$baseDatos = new Basededatos('localhost', 'root', '', 'phpavanzado');
$productos = new Productos($baseDatos);

El codigo para insertar la compra, en carpeta componentes.
<?php
include('componentes/recursos.php');
include('clases/carrito.php');
$compras = new Carrito($baseDatos);
$compras->introducir_compra($_GET['codigo']);
header('Location: ../unidad7.php');


y el index
<table class="tabla">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Código</th>
                <th>Producto</th>
                <th>Descripción</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
            <?php 
            $mostrarProductos = $productos->listarProductos();
            for ($i=0; $i < count($mostrarProductos); $i++) { 
    
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td> <?php echo $mostrarProductos[$i]['codigo']; ?></td>
                <td> <?php echo $mostrarProductos[$i]['producto']; ?></td>
                <td> <?php echo $mostrarProductos[$i]['descripcion']; ?></td>
                <td> <?php echo $mostrarProductos[$i]['precio']; ?></td>
                <td><a href="componentes/insertarCompra.php?codigo=<?php echo $mostrarProductos[$i]['codigo']; ?>">Comprar</a></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>    
    </table>
    </section>
    <aside>
        <h3>Carrito de Compras</h3> 
        <table class="compras-tabla">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Producto</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php 
            $mostrarCompras = $compras->listar_compra();
            for ($i=0; $i < count($mostrarCompras); $i++) { 
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td> <?php echo $mostrarCompras[$i]['producto']; ?></td>
                <td> <?php echo $mostrarCompras[$i]['precio']; ?></td>
                <td><a href="componentes/eliminar.php?codigo=<?php echo $mostrarCompras[$i]['codigo']; ?>">Quitar</a></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>    
           
    </table>    

Los productos de la tabla en mysql pude traerlos, pero no logro hacer funcionar el insertar compra.

¿Cuál es el valor de $codigo en ese contexto? ¿Has verificado que el resultado de SELECT producto, descripcion, precio FROM productos WHERE codigo=$codigo produce un resultado válido para ser insertado en la tabla compras. ¿Cuál es la estructura de esa tabla? El control de errores brilla por su ausencia en tu código. Por eso no sabes lo que está fallando. Establece  control de errores, mostrando al usuario final mensajes oportunos sobre lo que está haciendo mal para que rectifique.

No aceptaste la respuesta en tu ultima pregunta aun cuando dijiste que la respuesta funciona. Acepta esa respuesta para que la gente se interese más en ayudarte...
